# How to foreach json or object data with java

Tags: java, json

I have a return from Web-Service like this :

```
Object result = envelope.getResponse();
```

AND the return is like this

```
[{"nom":"Nexus09","poste":"4319"},{"nom":"Nexus08","poste":"4312"},{"nom":"Nexus07","poste":"4306"}]
```

I need to foreach the result to get "nom" and "poste" for every `{"nom":"Nexus09","poste":"4319"}`

THX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access each key and value in JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696713/how-can-i-access-each-key-and-value-in-jsonarray)

Answer (score 1):

Using http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20180813/json-20180813.jar Jar,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="[{\"nom\":\"Nexus09\",\"poste\":\"4319\"},{\"nom\":\"Nexus08\",\"poste\":\"4312\"},{\"nom\":\"Nexus07\",\"poste\":\"4306\"}]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(input); 

    jsonArray.forEach(j->System.out.println(j.toString()));     

}
```

To parse the nested `JSONObject`, It can be done like below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="[{\"nom\":\"Nexus09\",\"poste\":\"4319\"},{\"nom\":\"Nexus08\",\"poste\":\"4312\"},{\"nom\":\"Nexus07\",\"poste\":\"4306\"}]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(input);         

    for(Object object:jsonArray) {
        if(object instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;

            Set<String> keys =jsonObject.keySet();
            for(String key:keys) {
                System.out.println(key +" :: "+jsonObject.get(key));;
            }               
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to loop through an array of JSON and also get all key-value pairs.
This should work.

Hope it helps.

Code:

```
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
}
for(JSONObject json : result)
{
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
    }
}
```